# Live Bootable Backup

Tags: 14.04, macbook-pro

I have a 500gb external hdd that I'm using to boot Ubuntu. I don't need 500gb it was just so I didn't mess up my internal drive running OS x. I just bought a 64gb usb that I would like to make bootable with all the stuff from my external drive(only using lk 18 gb). Everything website I've found says I need 500gb(same size) or bigger to clone the drive and settings. Is there any way to make the 64gb drive bootable by cloning from my external drive?

Comment: Why dont you just install the OS onto the 64gb USB drive and then transfer the files from the 500gb drive to the newly created OS. I have found tutorials on how to do what you are asking but have never been able to get them to work.  I can't find those tutorials now but I will keep looking and link you when i find them.  Just beware it will be quite the effort to do as you are asking

Comment: Yea seems like the more I look the bigger pain it is. You think I can install the os then transfer the settings somehow?

Comment: What OS are we talking about and what settings exactly?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. And pretty much all the battery tweaks I got the new 3.18 kernel, cpu-freq, tlp, enabled p_state. media is easy but programs like compiz, tweak took and stuff that would be a pain to refind everything and reinstall it all.

Comment: yea I can't see why that wouldn't work actually, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two options:

1. You could copy all the deb files for the packages you have installed from `/var/cache/apt/archives` just so long as you haven't ran `sudo apt-get clean` to specifically remove these files
2. I have always used `aptoncd` which is my recommendation.

Just open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

From their webpage:

> Create a removable repository with all packages downloaded with Synaptic, apt-get or aptitude.

This gives you a fancy GUI to make backups of all your programs, it is capable of others things as well but this is what I have always used it for.  [Here](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/doc-manual.html) is their website.

Comment: ok just so I understand, as far as settings those are kinda out the window, but everything I've installed is basically backed up right?

Comment: You could look up the location of the config file for each application and copy them over to the corresponding place in the new OS.  For most apps I don't think this would be worth it but for a couple it might be, such as: Conky, Unity Tweak that kind of thing.